# :before overlay doesn't cover image when hovered on

Tags: html, css

So what I want is that when an image is hovered over the black overlay I have added with the :before covers the div and then I will add text and an image over the top of that later. With the current code it doesn't even seem to be recognising the hover. I'm also using foundation. Help would be much appreciated :)

```
<div class="small-12 large-4 columns">
        <img class="tri" src="media/images/mountain.jpg">
      </div>



.tri{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.tri:before{
  opacity: 0.8%;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';

}

.tri:hover::before{
  top: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, `::before` and `::after` psuedoclasses aren't supported on self-closing elements like `img` and `input`.

You could simply wrap an additional `div` around the `img` and put the `:hover` and `::before` properties on that.

Comment: Hi Jon, Added it to the div surrounding it and it worked perfectly. Thank you :)